# How do bitwise operations work in Python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I have been learning about Bitwise operations today and I learned that Not (~) inverses all bits, e.g.:

```
01010
to
10101
```

which means ~10 should be -5 but instead I have seen that it is -11 (per the python command line) which is

```
01010
to
11011
```

only two of the bits have been inverted. Can anybody explain why it isn't 10101?

EDIT: After looking on my calculator I understand it a little better, But my own code for determining binary and ints is still being confused. Entering in (in byte mode) 11110101 gives me -11 but the same entered in my code gives -117:

```
def binaryToInt(biNum, bUnsigned = False):
    iNum = 0
    bSign = int(biNum[0]) if not (bUnsigned or biNum[-1] == "u") else 0
    biNum = biNum[(1 if not (bUnsigned or biNum[-1] == "u") else 0):(len(biNum) if biNum[-1] != "u" else -1)]
    for i in xrange(len(biNum)):
        iNum += int(biNum[i]) * 2**(len(biNum) - 1 - i)
    return (iNum if not bSign else -iNum)

def intToBinary(iNum, bUnsigned = False):
    bSign = "1" if iNum < 0 else "0"
    iLoopNum = int((iNum ** 2) ** 0.5) #make positive!
    biNum = ""
    while iLoopNum:
        biNum += str(iLoopNum%2)
        iLoopNum /= 2
    return bSign + biNum[::-1] if not bUnsigned else biNum[::-1] + "u"
```

can one of you explain that?

Comment: @MrLister: you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`11011` is *not* -11. You have a misunderstanding of the encoding scheme for negative numbers.

In two's complement, -11 is `10101` which is the correct bit inversion.

To negate a two's complement number, you invert all bits and add one:

```
01011 eleven
10100 invert
10101 add one gives negative eleven
```

Comment: At least, in a 5 bit system.

Comment: If you have more bits, you simply sign extend (prefix with one bits on the left). I used 5 bits because the question showed 5 bits. However, it's exactly the same process no matter the width.

Comment: We're all in agreement here, of course, but I'm just saying the number of bits is important, because the highest bit is the sign bit. In your example, you use the 4th bit from the right as the sign bit, but it doesn't work like that in the real world. You can't choose how many bits you want in a number, because the system has made the choice for you, and you don't have a say in that. You can't decide that the 4th bit from the right is the sign bit.

Comment: so why do they have to use the Twos Complement System instead of reserving first bit for sign (as in C++ Unsigned and Signed ints) because 10101 (or -0b101 as bin type) is -5? Just confusing lol

Comment: @J_mie6 In the two's complement system, the most significant bit *does* indicate the sign of the number. If it bit is set, then the number is negative. If not, then it's zero or positive. The benefits of 2's complement over the signed bit system are many, which you can look up yourself. One such advantage is that the number 0 has only a single representation (as opposed to 0b000 = 0 and -0b000 = -0 = 0 in the signed bit system.

Comment: Furthermore, The C++ standard *does not specify* a system for representing signed ints, but practically speaking, compilers **do** use 2s complement on typical hardware, because the hardware is specifically designed for it.

Comment: @MrLister: In Python, the number of bits isn't important, because there is no set number of bits. Conceptually, a negative number has an infinite number of `1` bits on the left; Python integers never overflow and use as many bits as they need, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the number of bits in a negative number.

Comment: @Karl, the C++ standard does indeed specify signed encodings. C++11 `3.9.1 Fundamental types /7`: "... this International Standard
permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types". Just like C.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that values are 32 bits, 10 is

```
00000000000000000000000000001010
```

and if you invert all those bits, you get

```
11111111111111111111111111110101
```

or -11. Because it's a [2's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)!

Comment: still confused because 11111111111111111111111111110101 
 in int form is -2147483637?

Comment: Funny, my calculator says 4294967285.

Comment: binaryToInt("11111111111111111111111111110101", True) = 4294967285L. Where True represents Unsigned putting False (signed)there gives the number I posted.

Comment: Conceptually, a negative number in 2s complement representation has an arbitrary number of `1`s on the left. You need to know how many are in use in order to convert the number. Python defines `~` so that the number of bits used to represent the result is equal to the minimum number of bits that would be needed to represent the input. The net effect of that, though, is that `~x` == `-x - 1`, in general.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel

Would it ever be useful to have ~ redefined to return the inverted number that I would expect?

Comment: @J_mie6 What _do_ you expect? Your example in your question turned out a misunderstanding in how negative numbers are represented, not in how "bit flipping" works.

Comment: @MrLister 

In a C++ tutorial where I first found about the operators the ~ operator was returning different numbers to the original, ie

~4 (int4) becomes 11 and
~4 (int8) becomes 251

Comment: the thing is, there is no 'int4' or 'int8' or 'intanything' in Python. That's like, part of the reason for using it :)

Answer (score 0):

10101 is -11, because in binary, -X = ~X + 1.

So ~X = -X - 1 
      = -(X + 1).